# Injecting a class instance to a generic interface

Tags: c#, interface, dependency-injection

I have this model class:

```
public class FunctieModel: ObservableObject
{ ... }
```

The base interface for repositories:

```
public interface IBaseRepo<T> where T : ObservableObject
{
    void Delete(int id);
    T GetItem(int id);
    IEnumerable<T> GetList();
    bool Update(T model);
    bool Insert(T model);
}
```

The specific interface for repository of type FunctieModel

```
public interface IFunctieRepo : IBaseRepo<FunctieModel>
{}
```

The implementation of the repository for my FunctieModels:

```
public class FunctieRepoSql : IFunctieRepo
{...}
```

My tester class that must be able to work with the repositories, which must be injected:

```
public class Tester    
{
    IBaseRepo<ObservableObject> repo;

    public Tester(IBaseRepo<ObservableObject> repo)
    {
        this.repo = repo;
    }
}
```

This all compiles fine. Now I need to instantiate the tester class with different repositories.

```
new Tester(new FunctieRepoSql())
```

This is where my problem is. The error is
cannot convert from `FunctieRepoSql` to `IBaseRepo<ObservableObject>`

I am obviously missing something. Anyone have a clue how I can get this to work?

Comment: You are looking for articles on "variance in C#" - something like `IBaseRepo<in ObservableObject>` may be the answer. You may try good duplicate yourself to be nice :)

Comment: He needs an `out`, not an `in`.

Comment: @Alexei, Preston, no he needs both.  (`T` in return types and method parameters)  Thus variance won't help.

Comment: To the OP, why don't you just pass `T` to `Tester`?

Comment: @KirkWoll - thought so (that's why I said "may") - did not pay enough attention to whole code. OP will need to specify what can be altered in the code to get it working (as basic interface change is not solving the issue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two key options to consider.  The easiest is to simply make `Tester` generic and consume a type parameter that you can pass to `IBaseRepo<T>`.

```
public class Tester<T> where T : ObservableObject
{
    IBaseRepo<T> repo;

    public Tester(IBaseRepo<T> repo)
    {
        this.repo = repo;
    }
}
```

Then you can change your calling code to:

```
new Tester<FunctieModel>(new FunctieRepoSql())
```

If for whatever reason you cannot use this technique, you could instead create another non-generic interface, `IBaseRepo` that `IBaseRepo<T>` extends.  It should surface equivalent methods as `IBaseRepo<T>` (for those methods that utilize `T`) but instead declare them without the use of that type argument.  This is analogous to `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>`.  Having done this, you could then make `Tester` accept an `IBaseRepo` in its constructor rather than the generic version.

Comment: That's it, I changed the Tester class to generic like you showed and it works as needed. 
Many thanks to you and all others to look into this!

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert `IBaseRepo<FunctieModel>` to `IBaseRepo<ObservableObject>`. For example imagine a generic collection of lets say cats, if you convert it to a collection of animals you'll be able to add a dog to it, which is undesirable. However, you can use `out` keyword here:

```
public interface IBaseRepo<out T> where T : ObservableObject
```

But then you won't be able to accept ObservableObjects as input ([msdn about out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx)).

Comment: While you're correct, I'm not sure how helpful this answer is since you yourself acknowledge it won't actually work with his type.

Comment: @KirkWoll but I can't redesign this application, and as it is it won't work (it  might be useful to be sure about it)